# Play 2.0.4 file upload. NullPointerException: null

Tags: file-upload, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play in Java and I have problem with Handling file upload.

I made everything like on [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFileUpload) page but I get `NullPointerException` when I submit the form.

Here is my form:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
<input type="file" name="picture">
    <p>
       <input type="submit">
   </p>
}
```

Route:

```
POST    /upload         controllers.Application.upload()
```

Here is my controller:

```
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart;

public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");  //here i got NullPointerException
    if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
        File file = picture.getFile();
        return ok("File uploaded");
    } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
    }
}
```

I've tried couple of solutions found on the Internet but none of them helped me.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Strange, the code is correct, also you have no errors in it (I checked it line-by-line). Are you working in dev mode ? maby you started application in production mode and it doesn;t reflect code changes, try to stop your app in the console with ctrl+c and run it with `play run` again, then check the form again. Show us also other imports (maybe you used some Scala version by accident...) If it's possible publish somehwere whole your code in the state as it is now

Comment: Rest of imports:

    `import java.io.File;`
    `import play.data.*;`
    `import play.mvc.*;`

About the rest of the code it's basically just simple app ToDoList from PlayFramework homepage tutorial with irrelevant changes in views. I need file uploading in my other application but I'm just testing it on this one. I used `body.asFormUrlEncoded()` and I noticed that value from `input type="file"` is not on this map but values from `input type="text"` are. Looks like the submit button doesn't pass picture forward. I'm using Play 2.0.4.

Comment: That's also correct, file(s) are available in `asMultipartFormData()`, tbh, I have no idea what's wrong, if you can't publish whole project - try to create new app and place your upload code only, it will probably run without problems, then you can examine yourself, if there is some differences between current and other codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `NullExceptions` in this place is for `body`  not for `picture`

The only possible reason is that you are sending it with HTML form which hasn't `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (maybe you didn't refresh the form in the browser and still trying to send a normal form?)

make sure (in your browser), that page where you're filling the form has this form declaration and try again.

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="picture">

    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works in every apps despite that one I tried to test file uploading at first :) NVM, all in all it's working :) Pozdrawia student PWR :)