# play does not recognize form

Tags: java, playframework

I am following the same tutorial as this guy, so my code is identical to his in this post: [Play 2.0.4 file upload. NullPointerException: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173323/play-2-0-4-file-upload-nullpointerexception-null)

however, my problem is different in that i have a compilation error, not a runtime error(yet).  I type "start" in the play console, and the compiler tells me:

not found: value form

This is the content of my index.scala.html:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

<input type="file" name="picture">

<p>
    <input type="submit">
</p>
}
```

Play is complaining it doesnt recognize the form template tag "@form".

According to this article, http://dylankobayashi.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/views-and-play/ the author thinks it's a windows specific issue, but I don't know what he means by CR and LF.

Finally, I was reading the play 2.1.3 javadoc for the MultiPartFormData class and didn't really understand it; can this accept any kind of file, including zip files?  Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your code then ???

Comment: it's the EXACT code he has in that stackoverflow question(we are both following the tutorial on the play site).  If you want me to copy and paste that code here I can, but I thought it would be easier just to read his code in that link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably just missing the import. The `form` tag (and all other built-in form element tags) are in the `views.html.helper` package.

You need to either include the package name when you use the tag:

```
@helper.form(...)
```

Or add the import at the top of your view:

```
@import helper._
```

The `._` at the end is the Scala equivalent of `.*` in Java imports.

Comment: It's bad that the documentation on forms doesn't mention this.